# SQL Top 2 Records/Values

Tags: mysql, sql, max, min

Hi I have the below query which returns data for the next start date in the start date table, what I am looking to do is pull data for the next 2 start dates rather. Can anyone help me please? I Have edited to show the specific part I am having an issue with rather than provide the entire query, please remember this is a sub query.

```
(a1.expstartdate = (select min(startdate) 
from cstreprts.dbo.startdates
where startdate+15 > @asofdate and sycampusid = a1.sycampusid) 
    or a1.startdate = (select min(startdate)
 from cstreprts.dbo.startdates where startdate+15 > @asofdate 
 and sycampusid = a1.sycampusid))
```

Comment: You should try to simplify your query to its minimal expression (at least for the question).

Answer (score 1):

You can `LIMIT` the amount your receive. If you `ORDER BY` descending value the `LIMIT` will only give you back your top 2 results.

Simply `ORDER BY` and then `LIMIT 2`

A short example

```
SELECT start_date 
FROM start_date_table 
ORDER BY start_date DESC 
LIMIT 2;
```